# No me permite almacenar los datos en clase years, ¿Cuál es mi error?

Tags: java

Deseo agregar los datos a mi clase *years*, pero me tira el error que no puedo convertir el *int* en *years*, cosa que no entiendo porque le estoy dando datos *int*.

```
public class mayor{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner datos = new Scanner (System.in);
        years anios []= new years [5];
        
        for(int i=0; i<anios.length; i++){
            System.out.print("edad: ");
            anios[i] = datos.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
    
//clase a la que deseo agregar info ----------
    
class years{
    private int edad;
    
    public years(int edad){
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public String retornoEdad(){
        return "edad: "+edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias colocar todo el codigo... como lo estas llamando porque veo varios errores...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la asignación que realizas `anios[i] = datos.nextInt();` funcionaria si el array fuese de tipo entero `int anios []= new int[5];` porque es lo que retorna `datos.nextInt();` pero lo que tu esperas es un objeto de tipo `years` que por buenas practicas debería de llamarse `Years` porque las clases inician con letra mayúscula, para que funcione la asignación debes de realizarla de la siguiente forma `anios[i] = new years(datos.nextInt());` utilizando el constructor para crear el objeto, el resultado final quedaría:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    years anios []= new years[5];
    Scanner datos = new Scanner (System.in);

    for(int i=0; i<anios.length; i++){
        System.out.print("edad: ");
        anios[i] = new years(datos.nextInt());
    }
   
   // se imprimen los datos dentro del array anios para comprobación 
   for(Years anio : anios){
       System.out.println(anio.retornoEdad());
   }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias,así era :3

Comment: @CollinZuniga , que bueno poder ayudarte, recuerda que toda pregunta en la cual recibas una respuesta correcta debes de marcarla como respuesta, para que la pregunta se muestre como contestada y ayude a dar visibilidad a la comunidad se SO